# Is it possible to control which record is deleted by arcpy's Delete Identical tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am revising a script that feeds earthquake data from the USGS's API into a geodatabase. Until recently, I had used arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management with a single field as the argument (the quake ID):

```
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management(eqdb, ["id"])
```

The problem with this approach is that the USGS will often update a quake a few hours or days after the initial report, but the ID remains the same on their end. This means that DeleteIdentical will recognize the update as a duplicate record, so it will delete it from the database and keep the outdated one. My solution to this was to add a second parameter: the "updated" field, which is a text field that tells me the last time a record was updated by the USGS.** Obviously, the "updated" field of an update differs in that is later than that of an outdated record:

```
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management(eqdb, ["id","updated"])
```

So now that the script can distinguish them from one another, I can keep both of these quakes in the database despite them having the same ID, which is great. My question is this: how does DeleteIdentical determine which duplicates it deletes? Is there a way I can use the "updated" field to make it delete only the older record?

**In case an example is helpful, the "updated" field uses this formatting for the date: "2021-09-29T17:51:16.853Z"

Comment: Are you asking you may have 2 or 3 points that have the same ID but all have different datetimes in this updated field and you want to remove all but the most current?

Comment: @Hornbydd Yep, you got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the basic logic laid out in a model which if you want you could convert into python.

[image: Model]

The Delete identical tool has no capability to query the data as it deletes, you need to take a different approach. Here I run a simple summary stats tool grouping by ID but getting maximum date (most recent). I join that temporary table to the Feature Class then select rows where the dates match, then invert the selection and delete them. Hey presto you are left with just the points with the latest date and for points where there are many points with the same ID you are left with just one with the latest date.

Recommend you explore this logic on a backed up dataset so you are happy with what it does.

Comment: You rock! This answer is so detailed and it works perfectly, save for the join removal at the end -- I'm executing this as a stand-alone script and the join seems to remove itself, so I omitted that part. Thank you so much!